# How to get label of select option with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, select

```
<select>
<option value="test">label </option>
</select>
```

The value can be retrieved by `$select.val()`.

What about the `label`?

Is there a solution that will work in IE6?

Comment: You mean how to get value of selected, the selected value ? which is in your case label ?

Comment: This question should be reworded to say "How to get **text** of select option with jQuery?" and all references to label should be replaced with text to avoid confusion with the label attribute.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('select option:selected').text();
```

Comment: This isn't always correct. The option's shown description can be specified by a 'label' attribute as well (except <= IE7).  See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_label.asp#gsc.tab=0 and http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6

Comment: To get the _label_ attribute, this can be used: jQuery('#theid option:selected').attr('label')

Answer (score 24):

Hi first give an id to the select as

```
<select id=theid>
<option value="test">label </option>
</select>
```

then you can call the selected label like that:

```
jQuery('#theid option:selected').text()
```

Answer (score 18):

For reference there is also a secondary `label` attribute on the option tag:

```
//returns "GET THIS" when option is selected
$('#selecter :selected').attr('label');
```

Html

```
<select id="selecter">
<option value="test" label="GET THIS">
Option (also called label)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 10):

I found this helpful

```
$('select[name=users] option:selected').text()
```

When accessing the selector using the `this` keyword.

```
$(this).find('option:selected').text()
```

Answer (score 7):

To get the label of a specific option in a dropdown yo can ty this --

```
$('.class_of_dropdown > option[value='value_to_be_searched']').html();
```

or

```
$('#id_of_dropdown > option[value='value_to_be_Searched']').html();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('select option:selected').prop('label');
```

This will pull out the displayed text for both styles of `<option>` elements:

- `<option label="foo"><option>` -> `"foo"`
- `<option>bar<option>` -> `"bar"`

If it has both a `label` attribute and text inside the element, it'll use the `label` attribute, which is the same behavior as the browser.

*For posterity, this was tested under jQuery 3.1.1*

Answer (score 2):

```
$("select#selectbox option:eq(0)").text()
```

The 0 index in the "option:eq(0)" can be exchanged for whichever indexed option you'd like to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers you do not need JQuery for this. Instead use

```
document.querySelectorAll('option:checked')
```

Or specify any DOM element instead of `document`

Comment: Presumably, you want to run it against the element, not the whole document. And to get the text value, you need to access `element.textContent`

Answer (score 0):

```
<SELECT id="sel" onmouseover="alert(this.options[1].text);"
<option value=1>my love</option>
<option value=2>for u</option>
</SELECT>
```

Answer (score 0):

Created working Plunker for this.
https://plnkr.co/edit/vR9aGoCwoOUL9tevIEen
`$('#console').append("<br/>"+$('#test_s :selected').text())`

Answer (score -2):

You're looking for `$select.html()`

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: That just returns the html for all option elements. The label text is /in/ there somewhere, but it's not the most efficient way to get at it.