# jquery get label value from dropdown

Tags: jquery

I know I can get the value using $("#dropdown").val()

does anybody know how i get the label?

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the text of the selected option of a select using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391019/how-to-get-the-text-of-the-selected-option-of-a-select-using-jquery)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get label of select option with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175737/how-to-get-label-of-select-option-with-jquery)

Answer (score 27):

```
var text = $("#dropdown").find("option:selected").text();
```

which is the same as

```
var text = $("#dropdown option:selected").text();
```

Comment: @BBonifield, *Vive la Revolución!* =) @mkoryak, +1 (and not *just* for beating Nick)

Comment: @BBonifield - It's not that hard to be faster anyone really...different people are mapped to different SO servers (IP hash) which have a cache refreshing at staggered intervals...which means one person may never see a question even appear on their unanswered list before it's been answered and upvoted before *that* server's cache refreshes, even constantly refreshing :)

Comment: @Nick, uhm, yea, nice theory.. just admit defeat!! ;)

Comment: @mkoryak - It's true :) During the day I don't even see  a ton of questions even in the categories I'm most active in, same goes for all users...you just don't realize it unless you look at the all questions by recent list :) (That is, if you *usually* look at "Unanswered" as I do)

Comment: this still only gets the text, not the label

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`:selected` selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) (to get the selected `<option>`) and get the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), for example:

```
$("#dropdown :selected").text()
```

Answer (score 4):

All these answers fail to answer the question. He's talking about the label, not the text. Label is a valid attribute of the option (`Specifies a shorter label for an option`). See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

To get the label use:
`$('#dropdown').find("option:selected").attr('label')`

Comment: that's the answer, which i am looking for.