# How to get the value of dropdown and display in label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown where I am filling the content with dynamic data and in the model I am appending my data to the dropdown

```
$("#dpp").append($("<option disabled></option>").val(0).html('Select Locations'));

$("#dpp").append($("<option selected='selected'></option>").val(1111).html('All'));
for (var i = 0; i < Location.length; i++) {                           
    $("#dpp").append($("<option></option>").val(data[i].sno).html(data[i].name));

}
```

I am unable to get the value and text of the selected option by using a change handler.

I tried:

```
$('#dpp').change(function () {
    var thisvalue = $(this + "option:selected").text();
    alert(thisvalue);
});
```

and by default on page load **All** option selected in the dropdown.

How can I get that value or text and show it on the label?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery get label value from dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838965/jquery-get-label-value-from-dropdown)

Comment: Duplicated question. Please check:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838965/jquery-get-label-value-from-dropdown

Comment: @CarlosMartins But how can i get the default selected value of dropdown ? suppose after clicking on the page the dropdown loaded and how can i get the default selected value

Comment: this is one way:
 $("#dpp option:selected").val();

Answer (score 1):

For change event and document ready:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  getSelectData($('#dpp'));
});

$('#dpp').on('change', function() {
  getSelectData($(this));
});

function getSelectData(el) {
  var $option = el.find('option:selected');
  var text = $option.text();
  var val = $option.val();

  alert('option text: ' + text + '; option value ' + val)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="name" id="dpp">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it is ok but when we load the page By default the one is selected right so how can we get that value/text with out using onload/load

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code for both purposes (on page load as well as on change event)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var dppText= $("#dpp option:selected").text(); // to get text on page load


 //to get text on change of drop-down
  $(document).on('change','#dpp',function(){
   var thisvalue = $(this + "option:selected").text();
   alert(thisvalue);
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$(document).on('change','#dpp',function(){
    var thisvalue = $(this + "option:selected").text();
    alert(thisvalue);
});
```

This will add `change` listener to the document level so you will be able to detect the `change` on `dpp`.

Comment: it is ok but when we load the page By default the one is selected right so how can we get that value/text with out using onload/load

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
$("#dpp option:selected").val();
```