# how to catch variable from mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to catch the corresponding id of the item, while choosing it from the select tag
and then post it via hidden input, in order to insert into another table with the item name.

In other words i want to insert the name of the item and the corresponding id:

```
    <form  action="interface.php" method="post">
    Equipment: <select name="equipment">
    <option value="0">Выберите оборудование</option>
    <?php
    $res = mysql_query('select `equipment_id`,`name`,`ip_adress` from `equipment`');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
         do
         {              
     printf("<option>%s</option>",$row['name']);
     $equipment_id = $row['equipment_id'];
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res));
    }
    ?>
    </select> 
    <input type="hidden" name="equipment_id" value="<?php echo $equipment_id;?>" />
```

Interface.php handler:

```
    <?php
    include("connect.php");

    $val1 = $_POST['equipment'];
    $val2 = $_POST['equipment_id'];
    $val3 = $_POST['vlan'];
    $val4 = $_POST['vlan_id'];
    $val5 = $_POST['name'];
    $val6 = $_POST['description'];


    mysql_select_db("ADRESSA") or die("Could not select database");

    $result_insert =  mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `ADRESSA`.`interface` (`equipment`, `equipment_id`, `vlan`,`vlan_id`,`name`,`description`) 
    VALUES   ('$val1','$val2','$val3','$val4','$val5','$val6');") 
            or die ("<b>Query failed:</b> " . mysql_error());

    if ($result_insert== 'true') 
    {
    echo "1 record added";
    header('Location: http://192.168.0.1/find/1/show_interface.php');
    }
    else{echo "try again";
    }
    mysql_close();

    ?>
```

The problem is that the values are inserted correctly only at first, and during the next queries it just adding the same values.

Best regards!

Comment: 1. Never ever trust user input 2. You are prone to SQL injection 3. You are using a deprecated API. All 3 can be solved using prepared statements

Comment: well, it is not quite inmportant on the current stage, all i really seraching for is how to make this work

Comment: your hidden field is outside any loop. only last value of loop is stored there. If you need to store the value of the "selected" option, then i think you may need some javascript code. If you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: please clarify your situation

Comment: i need to insert both name and id, while selecting name from the select tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the output on the form-side becomes something like this:

```
<select id="selEquipmentId" name="equipment_id">
    <option value="0">Выберите оборудование</option>
    <option value="1">Some Equipment Name (with the ID set in the value attribute)</option>
    <!-- 
    ... more options using the same patern
    -->
</select>

<!-- this hidden input element should contain the equipment name of the selected option -->
<input type="hidden" id="selEquipment" name="equipment" value="Выберите оборудование" />
```

Then using some javascript and [JQuery magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175737/how-to-get-label-of-select-option-with-jquery#answer-2175757) include the following script on the same page. Also [include JQuery](http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-39-s-cdn-provided-by-maxcdn) if you haven't already.

```
<script>
$('#selEquipmentId').on('change', function() {
    $('#selEquipment').val($('#selEqiupmentId option:selected').text());
});
</script>
```

**One last tip:** Use one loop for creating the options. Right now you're using a "do while"-loop inside of a while-loop (and as far as I can see the while-loop executes only once). This just creates confusion.